# how to pass image from one page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get image by image-handler in first page and how to pass into second page

The .aspx page is like

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="290px"
     ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("idnews") %>' />
```

Comment: you can send images's ID by Query String

Comment: This might help u... http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/432793/passing-an-image-between-pages

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the name of the image on the second page and set the same on the second page.

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("idnews") %>' Height="250px" Width="290px"/>  this is the  coding used in first page

Comment: from where do you want go to next page. Means by using which source `link` or `button` or what??

Comment: put the html of the button in your question. where is the image button inside a grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and implement according to your code

```
<asp:HyperLink 
          ID="lnkImage" runat="server" 
          ImageUrl='<%# Eval("productid","~/Handler.ashx?productid={0}") %>'
          NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("productid","ProductLarge.aspx?productid={0}")' />
```

and markup in ProductLarge.aspx should be,

```
<img src='Handler.ashx?productid=<%=Request["productid"] %>' alt='Large Image' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching image from database, so its not very big deal. You can just pass the Image id via Query string or other method and can display image as u display it on previous page.